# How to produce a normalized cumulative histogram?

Tags: data-visualization, python, normalization, histogram, numpy

I am having trouble understanding the proper method to calculate specific histograms, specifically with regard to cumulative and normalized histograms. If I want to calculate a normalized cumulative histogram, is it okay to first normalize the data and then apply accumulation? If the question is clear, you can skip ahead to the plots further below; otherwise, I've provided sample python code To illustrate my misunderstanding.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5]) + 0.5
# data consists of 5 occurrences 1.5, 4 occurrences of 2.5's, 3 occurrences of 3.5, etc
bins = np.linspace(1, 6, 6)

def accumulate(bin_counts):
    """ This function returns the cumulative sum of bin_counts. """
    return np.cumsum(bin_counts)

def normalize(bin_counts):
    """ This function returns the modified bin_counts such that they sum to one. """
    return bin_counts / np.sum(bin_counts)

# calculate histogram
bin_counts, bin_edges = np.histogram(data, bins=bins)
# calculate midpoints of bins
bin_middles = (bin_edges[1:] + bin_edges[:-1])/2
# calculate array of each bin-width (one per bin)
bin_widths = np.diff(bin_edges)
```

The code just below will print the bin specs in a readable format via terminal.

```
print("\n{} DATAS:\n\t{}\n".format(len(data), data))
print("{} BINS:\n\t{}\n".format(len(bins), bins))
print("{} BIN COUNTS:\n\t{}\n".format(len(bin_counts), bin_counts))
print("{} BIN EDGES:\n\t{}\n".format(len(bin_edges), bin_edges))
print("{} BIN MIDDLES:\n\t{}\n".format(len(bin_middles), bin_middles))
print("{} BIN WIDTHS:\n\t{}\n".format(len(bin_widths), bin_widths))
```

The code below allows for the creaion of a plot of the histogram data.

```
def organize_binstogram(bin_middles, bin_counts, width=bin_widths, align='center', first=None, second=None):
    """ """
    func_dict = dict(norm=normalize, accum=accumulate)
    if first is not None:
        func_first = func_dict[first]
        bin_counts = func_first(bin_counts)
        print("{} BIN COUNTS AFTER {} SUM TO {}:\n\t{}\n".format(len(bin_counts), first.upper(), sum(bin_counts), bin_counts))
    if second is not None:
        func_second = func_dict[second]
        bin_counts = func_second(bin_counts)
        print("{} BIN COUNTS AFTER {} SUM TO {}:\n\t{}\n".format(len(bin_counts), second.upper(), sum(bin_counts), bin_counts))
    plt.bar(bin_middles, bin_counts, width=width, align=align)
    plt.xticks(bin_middles)
    plt.show()
```

To call the function just above, one can run any of the following:

```
# organize_binstogram(bin_middles, bin_counts, first=None, second=None)
# organize_binstogram(bin_middles, bin_counts, first='norm', second='accum')
# organize_binstogram(bin_middles, bin_counts, first='accum', second='norm')
```

Running the code above will produce the following plots:

**No accumulation or normalization**
[image]

**Apply accumulation and then normalization**
[image]

**Apply normalization and then accumulation**
[image]

I believe that the last version (normalizing and then applying accumulation) is correct. But I think I may be misunderstanding and wanted to verify that this method is actually correct.

Comment: If you first cumulate and then normalize by dividing by the last (that is, largest) cumulated value, you should get correct results.